# How to handle garbage collection/ free resources when using SwfDotNet

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I am able to read the height & With of the `.swf` file & if it isn't within the specified dimension then i have to delete the file from the server, Unfortunately it keeps generating error as i am not able to free resources, I am not sure what other resources i have to free.

[Tutorial link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19970/Reader-of-SWF-Header-File-in-Pure-C?msg=4448020#xx4448020xx)

**The process cannot access the file 'C:\PROJECTS\xyz\images\banners\file.swf' because it is being used by another process.**

```
/* Not using below case as i not able to dispose the swfReader object which can result in unnecessary memory*/

   // Create a swf stream reader
   SwfReader swfReader = new SwfReader(path);
   // Read the completed swf file
   Swf swf = swfReader.ReadSwf();
   // Read only headers of file to optimize read speed
   //Swf swf = swfReader.ReadSwfHeader();
   int swfHeight = swf.Header.Height;
   int swfWidth = swf.Header.Width;
   swfReader.Close();
   if ((swfHeight > int.Parse(hdnBannerHeight.Value)) || (swfWidth > int.Parse(hdnBannerWidth.Value)))
   {
       lblImageUploadMessage1.Text = "File cant be upload as it has invalid dimensions";
       lblImageUploadMessage1.CssClass = "lblErrorMSG";
       Session["bannerImage"] = null;
       if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) { System.IO.File.Delete(path); }
   }
```

Above code generates related to file being used by other process, I am not able to use `IDispose` method so i am not sure how to resolve this issue. I simply use FileUpload server control to upload file on asp.net web form.